# how to use views declared in one layout xml file in other layout

Tags: android

Respected All,
              I am newly working on android technology. I have use map view which is declared in another layout.I have to display in some part of may screen. can I use same map view or i have to create new mapview programmatically. In short i have to display map in some part of my screen. How can i do it..
                                                                          Thank You
                                                                         (Vikram Kadam)

Comment: Your title doesn't match your description actually. Are you trying to insert your mapView in another xml file or simply using the same layout for 2 different activities?

Comment: Sephy, I will make more clear. I have to display particular place information on screen with map location of that place. for that i have to show map in some part of screen. All data and map are in scrollview. So for that i have to create new MapView or i can use previously created map view by using findviewbyid which is in another layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the tag `<include>` . From the google documentation :

```
<com.android.launcher.Workspace
android:id="@+id/workspace"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
launcher:defaultScreen="1">

<include android:id="@+id/cell1" layout="@layout/workspace_screen" />
<include android:id="@+id/cell2" layout="@layout/workspace_screen" />
<include android:id="@+id/cell3" layout="@layout/workspace_screen" />

</com.android.launcher.Workspace>
```

You can find a full explanation [in the documentation.](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would define the view in a XML file and then every time you need it, you can inflate the View from the XML file.